# How to delete multiple files using Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$('.remove_proposal_file').unbind('click').bind('click', function(){

            var file_row_id = $(this).attr('fileid');
            var obj = $(this);

            $.ajax({
                url : '<?=base_url();?>project/remove_proposal_file',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                   frow_id: file_row_id,
                   action: 'remove_file_supplier',
                  '<?=$csrf['name'];?>': '<?=$csrf['hash'];?>'
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    var arr = $.parseJSON(data);    

                    if(arr['status'] == 1   ){
                        $(obj).parent().remove();
                        $('.file_remove_msg').show();
                        setTimeout(function(){ $('.file_remove_msg').hide(); }, 7000);
                    }

                    click_handler();
                }
            }); 

        });
```

Above code is written for deleting single file. I want to delete multiple file so how can I delete?

Comment: it depends on the api you have.

Comment: add you `project/remove_proposal_file` code

Comment: Go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for a better question

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about how to make multiple AJAX requests from the browser to remove files one-by-one. However, this is the wrong way to do it.

Presently you are deleting files singly by `post`ing to this address:

```
url: <?=base_url();?>project/remove_proposal_file
```

The relevant file parameter is:

```
frow_id: file_row_id
```

I would suggest then that you implement a server endpoint to delete multiple files like so:

```
url: <?=base_url();?>project/remove_proposal_files
```

And supply an array of frows like so:

```
frow_ids: [file_row_id_1, file_row_id_2, ...]
```

In order to do that, you'll need to ensure your interface allows multiple files to be selected, and then you can write a jQuery statement to read which ones are selected. This will form the basis of the input array to the new endpoint I have suggested.